# Appending a table row in mvc 3 with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-table, append

I am trying to append a table cell using the following javascript function:

```
function fn() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().append("<tr><td >some text</td></tr>");
}
```

and have a link inside a table cell `<td></td>` with the following link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fn();">+</a>
```

I am very new to jquery and am just trying to append a table with any text for now but nothing is happening when I click the link inside the table cell.

I am using MVC and razor, could anyone me get this to work?

Comment: that's a lot of calls to ancestors :). why not give some classname or id to the table and append rows to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `this` to your function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fn(this);">+</a>
```

And

```
function fn(elem) {
    $(elem).closest('table').append("<tr><td >some text</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I made the changes you suggested but now Firebug gives me the error "root is not a function".. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to not use inline javascript and instead bind the event to the anchor tag using jQuery.  For example:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="addnewrow">+</a>
```

Javascript

```
$("#addnewrow").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("table").append("<tr><td >some text</td></tr>");
});
```

I added the id to the anchor tag just as an example.  You can use whatever selector you would like to target the anchor tag.  (ie $("table a"))